# I want to get the value of the input box next to the button by jquery

Tags: jquery, django

I want to get the value of the input box next to the button

html

```
<span>
    <input type="text" value="{{p.filename}}" id="file_{{p.id}}" size=60 onclick="copy_for_file_name({{p.id}})">
    <button class="badge badge-pill badge-dark file_history_button" name="button">history</button>
</span>
```

but it's not work

```
// file_history_button
$('body').on('click', '.file_history_button', function (e) {
    const file_name = $(this).siblings().find('input').val();
    alert("file_name : ", file_name);
});
```

result is empty

do you know what is wrong?

Comment: Are you using react and jquery? If you are using react, it will be good to handle that using react by attaching ref to the input, manipulating DOM with jquery when you are using react which is used to manipulate UI

Comment: no this is django + jquery thanks for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use siblings with selector or `prev()` to get the previous input field.

```
    const file_name = $(this).prev('input').val();  
    const file_name = $(this).siblings('input').val();
```

```js
// file_history_button
$('body').on('click', '.file_history_button', function (e) {
    const file_name = $(this).siblings('input').val();
    console.log(file_name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>
    <input type="text" value="{{p.filename}}" id="file_{{p.id}}" size=60 onclick="copy_for_file_name({{p.id}})">
    <button class="badge badge-pill badge-dark file_history_button" name="button">history</button>
</span>

<span>
    <input type="text" value="{{p.filename2}}" id="file_2" size=60 onclick="copy_for_file_name({{p.id}})">
    <button class="badge badge-pill badge-dark file_history_button" name="button">history2</button>
</span>
```

Comment: I think it's because I use .file_history_button in several places on one page
Thanks

Comment: Hardly matters if you are having multiple buttons with same class as we searching siblings near the button which is clicked. Check console for result https://jsfiddle.net/z9o5v8pL/